# In Adobe Acrobat 2020, how do I make the print dialog box automatically appear when a PDF file is opened?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, acrobat-scripting

I do not see any such option under the **Initial View** tab in the **Properties** of the **File**.

Comment: you want to change how your computer works or how somebody elses computer works. But generally i dont think you can do this.

Comment: Auto-print a PDF when it's opened?.. that's *probably* a bad idea. But I'd *guess* it could probably be done with an embedded javascript. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript

Comment: @Scott - could be done maybe, but I agree it's perhaps a bad idea.  Might be perceived as just annoying, like how pop-ups are annoying.  Printing is generally a user-initiated process/choice. What if someone wanting to read the PDF has no printer (or paper, or toner), forcing them to press Cancel every time they open the document.  Yeah, really bad idea.

Comment: So, I do not know for sure if the current Acrobat version supports this, but on windows,  the command line switch `/t` followed by the PDF file name used to open the PDF and print it. At some point, you could specify the printer by name, but I usually just set the desired printer as default before running it. If combined with a shell script tied to a custom shell context menu, then a person could right-click and print. Some software like foxit I think adds a straight to print context menu.

Comment: see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference

Comment: And yeah, I agree that auto-printing on open is a user nightmare unless triggered specifically by the user

Comment: @Scott, no, the intention is not to "Auto-print", but merely to open the print dialog box along with the document. The user _can_ click on **Cancel** in the dialog box if they do not want to proceed with printing the document. I know that that is a thing because I have been sent PDF files that do this. Whilst I understand and agree unsolicitedly proposing to a user to print a document could be annoying, the document this relates to is one that _has_ to be printed and signed in ink by several different parties.